# Geodesic polygon on GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to show a geodesic polygon on GoogleMaps. I thought it is enough to just add geodesic:true to polygon options. But it is displayed linearly despite its huge size. Am I doing it wrong or it is not supported ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.body, {zoom:9,center:{lat:49.8,lng:18.2}});
    new google.maps.Polygon({geodesic:true,map:map,
        path:[{lat:50,lng:18},{lat:49.3,lng:18.5},{lat:50,lng:19}]});
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="position:absolute;width:99%;height:99%">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you are to centerd try move the polygon near pole

```
 window.onload = function() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.body, {zoom:9,center:{lat:49.8,lng:18.2}});
   new google.maps.Polygon({geodesic:true,map:map,
    path:[{lat:70.0,lng:18.0},{lat:70.0,lng:22.5},{lat:50.0,lng:22.5},{lat:50.0,lng:18.0 ]}  );
 }
```

(and as suugestion use float ever)

Comment: Thanks. I did not realized the projection is so close to linear in a 100km range.

Comment: the area between lat 50 , -50 is pratically plane for not very large aree ..